# Does a Sharing Set access of read only for Account over-ride the Community User's access to edit their Account?

Tags: sharing, customer-community, sharing-sets

We are using Customer Community Licenses for our Napili community. This is a membership community. We would like all members to read all contacts and accounts so I created sharing sets for both set at Read Only:

User:Account.Parent = Account:Parent  (Read Only)
User:Account.Parent = Contact:Account.Parent  (Read Only)

How can I give the User Read/Write access to their own contact and account record?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can provide access to same object based on 2 different criteria in sharing sets.

What you may need to do is to switch it around

1.Provide read access to all accounts and contacts using without sharing class

2.Change the sharing set to provide read/write access to their own account/contact.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am new to all of this and do not understand how to put in place #1. Could you provide more information please?

Comment: For 1 just create a a custom apex class and query the information as you like. Just mark the class as without sharing